# React how to add counter in useCallback

Tags: reactjs

I want to generate next numbers 1,2,3,4 in my useCallback to display rows with column ordinalNumbers. How to do that? I don't have any idea...

```
 const [lastNumber, setLastNumber] = useState(1);
    const getNumber = () => {
        console.log(lastNumber);
        setLastNumber(lastNumber+ 1);
        console.log(lastNumber);
        return lastNumber;
    };


 const getItems = useCallback(() => Service.getwarehouseList(id)
        .then((res) => ({
            items: res.map((warehouse) => ({
                id: warehouse.id,
                warehouseNumber: getNumber(),//how to increase number every time by one?
                name: warehouse,
                warehouseType: warehouse.ramp_type,
                operationType: warehouse.operation_type,
                editWarehouse: warehouse,
            })),
            done: true,
        })), [warehouseId, Service]);
```

Comment: which `useEffect`? please show a complete example...

Comment: @thedude sorry, I mean useCallback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map function callback gets a loop index as second parameter.
You could utilize this `index` to count the items:

```
        items: res.map((warehouse, index) => ({
            id: warehouse.id,
            warehouseNumber: index + 1, // index starts at 0, so add one to start counting at 1.
            name: warehouse,
            warehouseType: warehouse.ramp_type,
            operationType: warehouse.operation_type,
            editWarehouse: warehouse,
        })),
```

Comment: YES! I forgot about index in .map   THANK YOU